# Are TCP connections on localhost secure?

Tags: security, sockets, authentication, tcp, localhost

### Domain

I am designing a piece of software ATM and I would like to hide necessary cryptographic operations behind a "crypto daemon", which accesses encrypted keys on disk and offers a high level, application specific interface to these operations.

The other programs have to:

- Authenticate to the daemon (valid authentication allows the daemon to decrypt the keys on disk)
- Issue commands to the daemon and receive answers

I have the idea of using TCP via localhost for these operations. After doing the TCP handshake, the program has to authenticate to the daemon and - if successful - crypto commands can be issued to the daemon.

### Actual Question

At least two assumptions have to hold, otherwise this is insecure by design:

1. TCP channels on localhost cannot be hijacked/modified (except by the admin/root)
2. TCP channels on localhost are private (cannot be peeked at) (except by admin/root)

Are these assumptions true? Why? Why not? Is anything else flawed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loopback connections are in general not subject to man-in-the-middle attacks (from other non-root processes on the same box, or from outside the box).

If you intend to use loopback as a poor-man's-transport-security (instead of TLS) you will have to ensure that both ends of the connection are suitably protected:

- On the client end, what is the consequence of an unauthorised low-privilege process being allowed to connect to the server? If client access is protected by a plaintext password, you might consider a brute-force attack against that password, and address that with password complexity and auditing of failures.
- On the server end, is it conceivable for a low-privilege process to cause the server to terminate (eg crash it with malformed input or resource exhaustion), and replace it with a trojaned listener that would steal the password from a client or return misleading results? You might consider using Unix's low port number protection to stop this (but then you have to worry about running as root/setuid/fork).

It depends on your threat model how much of a concern you have with protecting against local access; you may take the position that your infra sec and monitoring is sufficient to discount the scenario of an attacker getting a low-privilege account. But in the general case, you may be better off biting the bullet and going with the well-known solution of TLS.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it explains best what the threats for the question's scenario are. TLS feels a bit wasteful to me since the whole encryption is unneeded - but doing the TLS authentication anyways sounds like an idea worth considering. Otherwise, I will be very careful with the two potential vulnerabilities you mentioned. Thanks to @Karthikeyan too for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's secure from everything except the kernel and other applications running in the localhost. If you can trust those, it's secure. If not, not.

Comment: The point is, I do not necessarily trust local processes. There may be proprietary software running or trojans etc.. If one of these programs has root/admin privileges, I concede (since it could dump and analyze my process's memory for instance); but as long as an untrustworthy program only has local privileges, my "crypto daemon" should not offer privileged operations before authentication. This is especially important on multiuser systems such as terminal servers.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer in any way. If you've got that problem, you also have the problem of someone impersonating your 'crypto daemon'. There is no end to this. It is up to you to define a perimeter within which you are secure.

Answer (score 2):

TCP packets would get routed back at IP layer itself, if the address is localhost. Since it is not passing through wires, it is not possible to get hijacked/ altered.

From Wikipedia, Relevant info is emphasized.

Implementations of the Internet Protocol Suite include a virtual network interface through which network application clients and servers can communicate when running on the same machine. **It is implemented entirely within the operating system's networking software and passes no packets to any network interface controller**. Any traffic that a computer program sends to a loopback IP address is simply and immediately passed back up the network software stack as if it had been received from another device.

Unix-like systems usually name this LOopback interface lo or lo0.

Various IETF standards reserve the IPv4 address block 127/8 (from which 127.0.0.1 is most commonly used), the IPv6 address ::1, and the name **localhost** for this purpose.